# upgrade 14.04 to 15.10 => option missing *set title*

Tags: 15.10

After upgrade 14.04 to 15.10 => option missing *set title*
How set title for new terminal?

Answer (score 1):

How to set Title
Click on `Terminal` menu. then click on `Set title`

[image]

Then enter your title in here and then click close.

[image]

as you can see the title has been changed.

[image]

Comment: Thx, but it not work for GNOME 3.14+